# Flink Monitoring: Capture statistics for more than 5 min

Tags: monitoring, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink community and I am trying to do a experimental study to capture performance of Flink for streaming data.
For this, I am trying to collect statistics of running jobs over a few hours. However, using Flink’s UI I can only see the statistics for the last 5 minutes.
I tried to hit the Rest API but that does not contain the data of statistics other than bytes read/written.

The metrics provided in the UI under Task Metrics are very helpful but do not scale beyond 5 min. Is there a way in which I can capture the entire history of metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a metrics reporter to record all the metrics that you are interested in over any period of time.

Flink 1.3 comes with reporters for JMX, Ganglia, Graphite, StatsD, and DataDog. The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html) describes to to configure a reporter.